# Email Addresses on the Stack Exchange "Contact Us" Page

Tags: support, advertising, contact

Should (some of) the email addresses on the [Stack Exchange "Contact Us"](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) page be at the Stack Exchange domain instead of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch. The contact page links to `@stackexchange.com` email addresses now.